# jqGrid is un-editable when loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a page that contains two radio buttons. On each radio button click, I have to load different editable grid in a div (using ajax).

When the page is loaded first time, "radio1" would be pre-checked, and the grid1 will be loaded into container div. When I click on "radio2", it should load a different grid into the same container div.

I have created two separate partial views to load different grids and grid setup is done within those partial views. On radio click, I execute an ajax call to load the result of the partial view into the container div.

When the page is first loaded, the grid1 is loaded and it is editable, But when I click on any radio button, it loads the grid properly but it looses editing capability (grid becomes un-editable).

I have spent a lot of time on this but can't find the problem. Please help.

Thanks

**Edit**

Here is the simplified code...

**MVC Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    //This returns the main page
     return view();
}

public ActionResult RenderGrid1()
{
    return PartialView();
}

public ActionResult RenderGrid2()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

**RenderGrid1 Partial View**
`<div id="jqGrid">`
`<table id="grid"><table>`
`</div>`

`<script>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //JS to initiate jqGrid 1
));
```

`</script>`

**RenderGrid2 Partial View**
`<div id="jqGrid">`
`<table id="grid"><table>`
`</div>`

`<script>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //JS to initiate jqGrid 2
));
```

`</script>`

**Details View**
`<input type="radio" name="group" id="group1" checked>Load Grid 1 <br>`

`<input type="radio" name="group" id="group2">Load Grid 2 <br>`

`<div id="dvContainer">`
`@Html.Action("RenderGrid1")`
`</div>`

`<script>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#group1").click(function(){
            loadGrid("RenderGrid1");
    });
    $("#group2").click(function(){
            loadGrid("RenderGrid2");
    });

    var laodGrid = function(action){
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: action,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#dvContainer").html(result);
                        }
            });
    }
}
```

`</script>`

**jqGrid Config for both partial views**

```
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        caption: "",
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Code'],
        colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true, edittype: "text" },
                { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', editable: true, edittype: "text" }
        ],

        other properties....
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I have added simplified basic code, thanks